# Cypress in a headless chrome mode: Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, testing, cypress

I have updated my Ubuntu (23.04, kernel Linux 6.2.0-32-generic) and Chrome (117), and `cypress run` command in a headless mode with a Chrome browser is not working now.
There were no problems when I use Chrome v115.

I try to run this command: `yarn cypress run --headless --browser chrome --spec path/to/mytest.spec.js` and getting an error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
 {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I will be grateful for the any answer or advice, thank you!

**Environment**:
Ubuntu: 23.04, Linux 6.2.0-32-generic
Cypress: v6.8.0
Chrome: v117
NodeJS: 18.16.1
NVM: v0.39.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by a [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1483163) `117` which affects Chrome `117`.
It was also logged as [Cypress issue 27804](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/27804) which lists different workarounds. This issue is now closed as resolved due to the release of the fix for Chrome (see below).

One of the workarounds listed in the Cypress issue is to update to a Cypress version > `12.14.0`. The other workarounds are more targeted to non-legacy versions of Cypress >= `10.0.0`. The Cypress `6.8.0` version you are using belongs to the legacy versions of Cypress so not all of the workarounds may apply exactly.

The following update to Google Chrome [Stable Channel Update for Desktop](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2023/09/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_27.html) resolves the issue:

> Wednesday, September 27, 2023
> The Stable channel has been updated to `117.0.5938.132` for Windows, Mac and Linux, which will roll out over the coming days/weeks.

Comment: Thank you! I have been updated my Chrome to version 117.0.5938.132 and now this is working

Answer (score 1):

Try using `--headless=new`  flag instead. https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/
As off 117 an old Cypress experiences the ECONNRESET error while connecting to the chrome in the old headless mode.
However Cypress now starts lots of chrome processes which keeps running after the Cypress id closed. It even hangs my workstation when is launched locally.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I cannot to check your advice, I have been updated my Chrome to version 117.0.5938.132 and now this is working :)

Answer (score 1):

For Older Versions of Cypress [I am using 9.7.0]

We have below options to workaround the issue for Chrome 117

1. Create a browser:launch hook to replace --headless to --headless=NEW

   setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
   on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
   if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
   launchOptions.args = launchOptions.args.map((arg) => {
   if (arg === '--headless') {
   return '--headless=new'
   }
   return arg;
   })
   }
   return launchOptions;
   })
   }
2. Run in Headed mode ->

   -b browser --headed